# Row Expander checking condition

Tags: extjs4

I have Grid with "rowexpander". with this I am able to expand the row, and able to show the content .i.e. html checkbox.
Now my requirement is the in my DB I got the value true or false. So depending upon the value i.e. true I want show check box with checked.

Here is my code.

```
    plugins: [
{
    ptype: 'rowexpander',
    rowBodyTpl:
    ['<ul><li><input type="checkbox" name="" checked={marginAccess} ><span>Margin Access for Quote</span></li></ul> ']
}
```

Now {marginAccess} when is it true I want to show ""
i.e. checked = checked

I am not able to do this, Can you please suggest me ?

Comment: What do you see in inspector? What's generated HTML inside this expanded row?

Comment: <input id="ext-gen1078" type="checkbox" checked="{false}" name="">

Comment: Really? With curly brackets? {}?

Comment: Nop, sorry I was trying at my end , for testing i have put extra bracket.It gives  <input id="ext-gen1078" type="checkbox" checked="false" name="">

Comment: So does 'false' represent what you need to get there? Or is it always false?

Comment: no it will either true or False, but when it is true then I want checked="checked" and not checked="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a virtual member in your model. One which will return 'checked/unchecked' for true/false value of other field. Like this:

```
{ name: 'marginAccess_str', type: 'string', convert: function(v, r) { 
  if (r.get('marginAccess')) 
     return 'checked';
  else 
     return 'unchecked';
}},
```

And then use marginAccess_str in your template.